# What do back brackets do in this bash script code?

Tags: linux, grep

so i'm doing a problem with bashscript, this one: ./namefreq.sh ANA should return a list of two names (on separate lines) ANA and RENEE, both of which have frequency 0.120.

Basically I have a file from table.csv shown in the code below that have names and a frequency number next to them e.g. Anna, 0.120

I'm still unsure what the `` does for this code, and I'm also struggling to understand how this code is able to print out two names with identical frequencies. The way I read the code is:

grep compares the word (-w) typed by the user (./bashscript.sh Anna) to the value of (a), which then uses the cut command to be able to compare the 2nd field of the line separated by the delimiter "," which is the frequency from the file table.csv and then | cut -f1 -d"," prints out the first fields which are the names with the same frequency

^ would this be correct?

thanks :)

```
#!/bin/bash
a=`grep -w $1 table.csv  | cut -f2 -d','`
grep -w $a  table.csv | cut -f1 -d',' | sort -d
```

Comment: They're called "backticks".

Comment: Any shell scripting tutorial should explain this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When a command is in backticks or `$()`, the output of the command is subsituted back into the command in place of it. So if the file has `Anna,0.120`

```
a=`grep -w Anna table.csv  | cut -f2 -d','`
```

will execute the `grep` and `cut` commands, which will output `0.120`, so it will be equivalent to

```
a=0.120
```

Then the command looks for all the lines that match `0.120`, extracts the first field with `cut`, and sorts them.